# How to represent Azure Function in Microsoft threat modeling tool?

Tags: threat-model

I am creating a data flow diagram for my application using Microsoft Threat Modeling tool. How can I represent Azure Functions as Azure template does not contain any element for that?

Answer (score 3):

There is another Azure template with more Azure Stencil Services located in the following GitHub repository:

[Azure Threat Model Templates](https://github.com/AzureArchitecture/threat-model-templates)

Answer (score 2):

*Note :- This is just a temporary solution and this stencil can be replaced with official Microsoft stencil for Azure Functions if they release in the future. And this solutions is only if you prefer to create your own rather than using 3rd party templates.*

You can add your own stencil to the Azure template e.g I created a new stencil as below. You can also add some constraints or property to the Azure functions stencil.

[image: Threat Model template with new stencil]

You can then add this stencil as target to the relevant threat types e.g as below

[image]